# Alternative for Enumerable.Single method for multiple objects?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, list

Edit: As paul mentioned I'm only accepting one possible value from each in the parameter. So by that logic they should be switched to lists. That causes a null reference exception though which I'm still trying to work through.

I'm trying to create a survey builder that has categories, questions, and answers. Currently when I try to update the data for the categories, questions, and answers, it only updates the first instance of each. I believe the problem is because I'm using the .Single method. Is there an alternative to this that is used for Lists?

Here are two of the examples that is only updating the first instance.

```
public ActionResult Save(Survey survey, List<Category> category, List<Question> question, List<Answer> answer)
{
     //var categoryInDb = _context.Categories.Single(m => m.CategoryId == category.CategoryId);
          //categoryInDb.CategoryDescription = category.CategoryDescription;

  //Updated loop.
      foreach (var categorytoAdd in category)
            {
                foreach (var categoryInDb in _context.Categories.Where(m => m.CategoryId == categorytoAdd.CategoryId))
                    categoryInDb.CategoryDescription = categorytoAdd.CategoryDescription;
            }

     var questionInDb = _context.Questions.Single(m => m.QuestionId == question.QuestionId);
          questionInDb.QuestionText = question.QuestionText;

     _context.SaveChanges();
     return RedirectToAction("Index", "Surveys");
}
```

in the view model they are defined as

```
    public List<Category> Categories { get; set; }
    public List<Question> Questions { get; set; }
```

Comment: As the `Save` method only receive one question/answer, how would you expect it to update multiple items?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you suspected `Single` only returns a single item that satisfies your condition. If you want *multiple* items you use `Where` (which of course returns an `IEnumerable`). Because its now a collection, you have to `foreach` over it to mutate/access/use items.

so:

```
foreach (var categoryInDb in _context.Categories.Where(m => m.CategoryId == category.CategoryId))
   categoryInDb.CategoryDescription = category.CategoryDescription;
```

As a sovemp noticed, you are `Single` will actually throw if you had more than one record to start with; so this won't do anything until you fix your overall query to have more than one result to return.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. That's what I was looking for. Unfortunately my data still isn't updating anything but the first instances so I'm guessing the problem lies somewhere else.

Comment: Do you have multiple categories with the same ID?

Comment: That's what I was wondering as well.  You are (it appears) only querying for 1 item of each, i.e. by the id of each object.  Furthermore, if more than one entry existed for your linq query, Single would throw an error ( as upposed to First).

Comment: SurveyId/CategoryId/QuestionId/AnswerId are all primary keys. They move down to foreign keys on each subsequent table respectively (surveyId is a FK to category, categoryId is a FK to question, etc)

So each category will have it's own categoryId, but can share a surveyId. In the same sense, question has it's own questionId, but can share a categoryId. The only one that is completely separate is the survey because it is at the top and can only be one.